# bitsets binary AND operation

Tags: c++, bitset

I wrote the following lines:

```
std::bitset<4> bitvec;  //bitset 0000
std::bitset<4> addition; //bitset 0000

addition.set(0); //setting the least significant bit

std::cout << addition << std::endl; //output 0001
std::cout << std::endl;

for(int x = 0; x != 16; ++x) { //addition loop
    std::cout << bitvec << std::endl; //output
    bitvec &= addition; //binary AND
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

and I expected the output to be:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
....
```

But the loop just outputs '0000'. What basic concept am I missing?

Comment: `bitvec` starts out zero, whatever you "and" it with, you will get zero. What were you expecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical AND is **not** addition.

Specifically,

```
  0000
& 0001
------
= 0000
```

Which explains why you always get `0000`.

Logical AND just looks at each bit in both bitsets and only outputs a 1 if that bit is 1 in both of the other vectors. As an example:

```
  1001
& 1100
------
= 1000
```

The reason that first bit is 1 is because the first bit in the other bitsets is 1. The rest are 0 because one of the bitsets has a 0 at that position.

If you want addition, don't use a bitset, and just use addition.

```
unsigned long a = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<4>(a) << std::endl;
    ++a;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/txuY8):

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first loop cycle
bitvec = `0000`
addition = `0001`

`0000 AND 0001` operation will result as `0000` and you assign the `0000` to `bitvec` and history repeating on the all next loop cycles.

Your expected results is a result of simple increment operation or +1 addition, basically just prin `x` in binary format. What are you trying to do with bitwise `AND`?

- [Bitwise AND operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)