# bitsets which implement addition and access to all bits

Tags: c++, bitset

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783837/bitsets-binary-and-operation) one, as I am looking for a way for adding bitset(-like) structures.
I need something like a bitset which can store at least 2400bits, and can (random) access all of them. The second important ability the class has to have is addition, I need to be able to add at least 1. The representation as a number wouldn't work (I guess) due to the possible size, which would be around 2,96 x10^722 and the uncomfortable bit access.
Is there any known efficient implementation?

Comment: Why not use a suitably sized array of `unsigned` (or `unsigned long`)? Yes, you'll have to implement the carry logic when adding them but checking for overflow and carrying the bit to the next `unsigned` should be relatively simple.

Comment: i hoped there already was an implementation with a nice interface

Comment: Almost certainly, but not part of the standard library as far as I know.

Comment: Use `vector<bool>`.  Its implementation as a bit vector is widely considered a mistake.  But pretty convenient right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [XInt](http://www.oakcircle.com/xint_docs/index.html). It is developed as a candidate for boost.

Comment: I will, thx. Is there any important reason why it is not (yet) officially a part of boost?

Comment: @Sim: no, it's just a long process.